# Fitness Sharing in multi objective optimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm, tournament, fitness

i'm writing a genetic algorithm that uses fitness sharing in tournament selection. in all the relevant literature that i found ([Sareni for example](http://jeffclune.com/courses/media/courses/2016-EvoRobot/readings/sareni-ReviewFitnessSharingAndNichingMethods.pdf)) it is mentioned that the solution's own fitness (Fi) should be divided by the sum of its niche distances (Mi).

What I don't understand is, as we are optimizing multiple objectives each solution has more than one fitness. what is then its 'fitness' Fi? should I see it as the multiplication of all its fitness's ?

for example, in the code i'm writing (processing):

```
float sharedFitnessA = (a.f2*a.f3) / nicheCountA;
```

thanks

n

Answer (score 1):

For multi objective optimization the goal of fitness sharing (*to distribute the population over a number of different peaks in the search space with each peak receiving a fraction of the population in proportion to the height of that peak*) is often pursued in a different manner.

When two candidates are either both dominated or both non-dominated (so it's likely that they're in the same equivalence class) niche count `Mi` is used to choose the "best fit" candidate.

E.g.

[image: Equivalence Class Sharing]

<sup>(here maximizing along the x-axis and minimizing on the y-axis)</sup>

Candidates aren't dominated by the comparison set. From a Pareto point of view neither is preferred. Using `Mi` we choose Candidate2 (smallest niche count and thus the least number of individuals in its niche).

This is called **Equivalence Class Sharing** and it isn't based on fitness degradation (i.e. `Fi / Mi`), but anyway maintains diversity along the front.

For further details take a look at [Multiobjective Optimization Using the Niched Pareto Genetic Algorithm](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.51.8761&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Jeffrey Horn and Nicholas Nafpliotis (it also contains some implementation details).